# Como verifico o tipo do Browser, versão e se da suporte a JavaScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Preciso identificar o browser, a versão do browser e se ele está habilitado para executar javascript.
Nas versões anteriores do Asp.Net eu fazia a verificação no Global.asax, usando o comando `Request.Browser.JavaScript`mas esse comando está setado como [deprecated] nos novos frameworks.

Comment: Acredito que esteja procurando algo como https://modernizr.com/

Comment: window.navigator.userAgent

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se possui todas as informações, mas este link aqui pode te ajudar bastante.

[Como ler as propriedades e informações do navegador](http://codigosimples.net/2014/04/16/como-ler-as-propriedades-e-informacoes-do-navegador-utilizado-em-mvc-c/)

Ex:

```
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase browser = Request.Browser;
        string s = "Browser Capabilities\n"
            + "Type = " + browser.Type + "\n"
            + "Name = " + browser.Browser + "\n"
            + "Version = " + browser.Version + "\n"
            + "Major Version = " + browser.MajorVersion + "\n"
            + "Minor Version = " + browser.MinorVersion + "\n"
            + "Platform = " + browser.Platform + "\n"
            + "Is Beta = " + browser.Beta + "\n"
            + "Is Crawler = " + browser.Crawler + "\n"
            + "Is AOL = " + browser.AOL + "\n"
            + "Is Win16 = " + browser.Win16 + "\n"
            + "Is Win32 = " + browser.Win32 + "\n"
            + "Supports Frames = " + browser.Frames + "\n"
            + "Supports Tables = " + browser.Tables + "\n"
            + "Supports Cookies = " + browser.Cookies + "\n"
            + "Supports VBScript = " + browser.VBScript + "\n"
            + "Supports JavaScript = " +
                browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + "\n"
            + "Supports Java Applets = " + browser.JavaApplets + "\n"
            + "Supports ActiveX Controls = " + browser.ActiveXControls
                  + "\n"
            + "Supports JavaScript Version = " +
                browser["JavaScriptVersion"] + "\n";
```